# Clearing received serial data from Arduino through a BlueTooth connection

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I have an Arduino UNO board connected via bluetooth to my Android phone. Everything is OK. Any command from android phone received and executed in Arduino. But the feedback from arduino is buggy.

This is first data from Arduino

```
device information :
pin 4 set to 0
pin 5 set to 0
pin 6 set to 0
```

but the second data is come like this

```
change pin 4 to 1n :
pin 4 set to 0
pin 5 set to 0
pin 6 set to 0
```

what i expected is

```
change pin 4 to 1
```

Here is android code i get from internet

```
mHandler = new Handler(){
  public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg){
  if(msg.what == MESSAGE_READ){
    String readMessage = null;
    try {
      readMessage = new String((byte[]) msg.obj, "UTF-8");
      //readMessage[bytes] = '\0';
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mReadBuffer.append(readMessage+"\n");
  }

  if(msg.what == CONNECTING_STATUS){
    if(msg.arg1 == 1)
      mBluetoothStatus.setText("Connected to Device: " + (String)(msg.obj));
    else
      mBluetoothStatus.setText("Connection Failed");
  }
  }
};

private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
private final InputStream mmInStream;
private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
  mmSocket = socket;
  InputStream tmpIn = null;
  OutputStream tmpOut = null;

  try {
    tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
    tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
  } catch (IOException e) { }

  mmInStream = tmpIn;
  mmOutStream = tmpOut;
}

public void run() {
  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  
  int bytes; 

  while (true) {
    try {

      bytes = 0;
      bytes = mmInStream.available();
      if(bytes != 0) {
        SystemClock.sleep(100); 
        bytes = mmInStream.available(); 
        bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer, 0, bytes); 

        mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget(); 
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      break;
    }
  }
}


public void write(String input) {
  byte[] bytes = input.getBytes();           
  try {
    mmOutStream.write(bytes);
  } catch (IOException e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Show Paired Devices", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mReadBuffer.append("Error Sending Data\n");
  }
}

public void cancel() {
  try {
    mmSocket.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {

  }
}
}
```

please help.

Comment: Are you sure that the Arduino is not to blame?

Comment: No.. i test using other app from playstore, the feedback is OK. But i need some function so i create myself. I also create desktop application using VB10, the result is OK

Comment: Could you show us the code for the Arduino? It looks like the message string that you use in Arduino is not cleared or the the BT serial communication is not flushed.

Comment: just usual code.

`... `
`initialization pin here`

`void setup(){`
`Serial.begin(9600);`
`}`

`void loop(){`
`Serial.println("change pin 4 to 1");`
`}`

Answer (score 0):

i dont know how this chould happen, but the rerspond is clear... some one can explain to me, or may be there is better answer??

```
mHandler = new Handler(){
  public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg){

    if(msg.what == MESSAGE_READ){
      String readMessage = "";
      /*
      try {
        byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
        readMessage = new String(readBuf, "UTF-8");
        readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0,13);
        readMessage[bytes] = '\0';
      } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      */
      readMessage = new String((byte[]) msg.obj, 0, msg.arg1);
      mReadBuffer.append(readMessage+"\n");
    }

    if(msg.what == CONNECTING_STATUS){
      if(msg.arg1 == 1)
        mBluetoothStatus.setText("Connected to Device: " + (String)(msg.obj));
      else
        mBluetoothStatus.setText("Connection Failed");
    }
  }
};
```